# How to deal with Vue.js siblings components with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-router

What I wanna do today is integrating Vue.js with Rails. Here is basically what I want to achieve :

[image: Vue.js Rails]

I have to create a Rails engine for this, and use Vue.js. I successfully integrated Vue with Rails, but here is my problem :

- The price should be sent by my controller in Rails
- When I make a choice and click on "Next", my cart should be instantly updated and total price calculated automatically
- When I click on "Previous", my cart should update
- And also, my progressbar on top should be automatically updated. But it's another story I can care later.

I don't know if I have to use Vue-Router or something. I think I should wrap all my Vue components in a parent component, but how can I handle "previous" and "next" links ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I simply don't know how to achieve all of this. My main question is : how can I basically make all of this thing functional ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, [Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) will do this for me. I didn't think Vue had this functionality in another module.

Comment: for this feature alone, a simple object as a stor would suffice, but vuex can indeed handle this.